# How to get shape or detect bezier path of shape in image?

Tags: ios, swift, border, uibezierpath, core-image

Need to achieve this by detecting shape path within the image. 
Creating images from bezier path is one solution but can we get path or draw a border around the shape with any other way?

Image will be in the even odd rule layer. How to detect path in it?

[image: This i]

Comment: still no answer ? anyone